# How to get the latest emails and append to the existing file instead of looping through all items using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code that loops through all Outlook emails under a subfolder and extracts the body of the email based on the subject. Code takes a lot of time to loop through all emails as there are thousands of them.

How do I modify the code to append data, extracted from the latest emails, to the existing file instead of looping through all the emails and overwriting again & again?

Let's say I want to run the code every day to get the prior day's email data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FinalMacro()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim iCounter As Integer
'iCounter = 1
Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear

' point to the desired email
Const strMail As String = "emailaddress@outlook.com"

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder
'Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim destCell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim oItem As Object

With ActiveSheet
    Set destCell = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set oApp = GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
If (oApp Is Nothing) Then Set oApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
On Error GoTo 0

Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("inbox").Folders("Other mails")

For Each oItem In oMapi.Items
    If oItem.Subject = "Volume data" Then

        ' get html table from email object
        Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable

        Set HTMLdoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        With HTMLdoc
            .Body.innerHTML = oItem.HTMLBody
        Set tables = .getElementsByTagName("table")
        End With

        Dim t As Long, r As Long, c As Long
        Dim eRow As Long

        For t = 0 To tables.Length - 1
            eRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            For r = 0 To (tables(t).Rows.Length - 1)
                For c = 0 To (tables(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                    Range("A" & eRow).Offset(r, c).Value = tables(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                Next c
            Next r
            eRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Next t
        
        Cells(eRow, 1) = "Date & Time of Receipt:" & " " & oItem.ReceivedTime
        Cells(eRow, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        Cells(eRow, 1).Font.Color = vbWhite
        Cells(eRow, 1).Columns.AutoFit

        Set oApp = Nothing
        Set oMapi = Nothing
        Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
        Set tables = Nothing

        wkb.Save '"C:\Users\Desktop\Trial_1.xlsm"
    
    End If
Next oItem
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code took took longer because of the line `wkb.Save` inside the loop (it saves the workbook on each iteration). Then it may extract last recorded `ReceivedTime` and condition the processed mails by it. The best idea is to use what @Алексей Р suggested (generically) in his answer. Looking to your code, I confess that I am not so sure that you will be able to apply it, no offence... It looks that you use pieces of code an combine them in a not too efficient way. If something unclear, you do  not have to hesitate and ask for clarifications. But it is not normal to not send any feedback...

Answer (score 0):

1. To quickly select (filter) latest emails, you can use [Items.Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict).
2. To use your workbook for the accumulative storage of information, you just need not to erase the sheet, but to find the last filled line and add the content from the letters after it.
   Smth like (**not tested**):

```
Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("inbox").Folders("Other mails")
    
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set append_ws = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' this worksheet is for appending

'Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear ' - remove this statement
    
' set filter to: non-flagged mailitems received < 1 day ago
flt = "[FlagStatus] <> 1 And [MessageClass]='IPM.Note' And [ReceivedTime]>='" & _
    Format(Now - 1, "ddddd 0:00") & "'"

Set Restricted = oMapi.Items.Restrict(flt)

For I = Restricted.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set oItem = Restricted(I)
    If oItem.Subject = "Volume data" Then
        content_from_email = "smth from letter"  ' get the content from the letter
        lastrow = append_ws.Cells(append_ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
        append_ws.Cells(lastrow, 1).Value = content_from_email
        
        oItem.MarkAsTask olMarkComplete ' set flag to the processed items
        oItem.Save
    End If
Next I
```

Comment: This throws an error to me. Do I need to declare both Restricted and flt as an object?

Comment: if you use `option explicit`, yes